# How to define "constant" structures in C

Tags: c, unix, struct, header

I am working on a relatively simple program in Unix, a client-server interaction simulating a restaurant.
Basically, the clients that enter the restaurant/server can order one or more dishes to send to the "cook" through a FIFO.
The menu has to be set somewhere and be accessible by both server and client. It has to be an array of dish structures. My first idea was including all this in a custom header file:
In shared.h

```
   typedef struct _dish{
   char name [MAX_LEN];     //name of food
   int id;                  //ID
   int preptime;            //time needed to prepare it
   } dish;

   typedef struct _request {    
   pid_t cpid;              //client pid
   dish menu [MENUSZ];      //array of dishes
   } request;
```

In this way the client chooses the dishes in a "randomish" way and sends the request to the server.
My problem is: how and where can I make a list of all the available dishes?
This "dish list" MUST be available for all the clients and defined apart.
To give an example of what I mean, I have to do something similar to this:

```
  dish dish1;

  dish1.name = "Pasta";
  dish1.id = 1;
  dish1.preptime = 5;
```

Something like this, a list stored somewhere and accessible by clients (and server most likely) that makes easier sending info to the server, so that I can just send the ID and the server already knows which food is it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you don't hack the compiler or libc, avoid using leading underscores - use trailing ones instead, if any (there's nothing wrong with using the same name for the structure and the typedef)

Comment: So you want to know how to initialize an array of `dish`?

Comment: Not how to initialize, but what's the best way. If I need to list let's say 10 different dishes, what's the best way to make them easy to reach and "use"? Can I include them into the header? Or should I create a menu struct, fill it from the server, and add it to the shared memory?

Comment: @EdoardoArnaudo: if you put them in a header, you need to recompile server and client both when the menu changes; depending on your requirements, a better design would be to put them in a config file on the server and have the client ask for it

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks! Your config file solution gave me a similar idea, creating a simple "menu.txt" and let the processes read from it with a sort of read function. Looks like working for my purposes!

Answer (score 0):

if you put them in a header, you need to recompile server and client both when the menu changes; depending on your requirements, a better design would be to put them in a config file on the server and have the client ask for it –  Christoph